# Mutate variable using indirection

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to modify one variable based on a second variable in a tibble.  Both variables should be referenced by indirection.

```
(x=data.frame(aa=1:4,b=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),c=c(TRUE,FALSE)))
v1='b';v2='c'
x %>% mutate({{v1}} := if_else({{v2}}==TRUE,FALSE,{{v1}}))
```

I want to modify b to false when c is true.  Otherwise b should be unchanged.  I want to use indirection using v1 and v2 to refer to the two variables.  Thus b should end up being `FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE`.  Doing this in a pipe is ideal.

Comment: There is no need to compare `{{v2}}==TRUE`, the variable already is a logical value. Can you post sample data?

Comment: The {{ embrace operator accepts symbols, not strings. If you change this to v1 = sym('b'); v2 = sym('c') it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn `v1` and `v2` into symbols and inject them into `mutate()` with `!!`:

```r
x %>%
  mutate(!!sym(v1) := ifelse(!!sym(v2), FALSE, !!sym(v1)))

#   aa     b     c
# 1  1 FALSE  TRUE
# 2  2  TRUE FALSE
# 3  3 FALSE  TRUE
# 4  4 FALSE FALSE
```